# не запускается компьютер после установки дополнительной оперативной памяти

Tags: память, железо

у меня есть 4 слота для оперативки. купил 4 платы по 2гб. когда вставляю все 4, то компьютер не запускается. запускается только если вставлю 2. подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли поставить все 4 и чтобы запускался компьютер? win 7 64bit

вот эту плашку пытаюсь вставить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скажите модель материнской платы. Точное полное название.

Comment: @AlexGlebe изготовитель NT Computer модель AGENT 6400/250.

Comment: Нет. Имеется ввиду не модель компьютера, которая нарисована красивой наклейкой на корпусе, а модель материнки. Той, куда ты вставляешь память. Российских производителей материнок за всю историю планеты я не знаю ни одного. Тут или Гигабайт или Асус или какой-нить Эпокс (если прям старое железо). Так-то я тоже могу перебрендировать айпод и назвать его `rumata music super player`, но айподом он быть не перестанет.

Comment: @AlexGlebe написано GA-945P-S3

Comment: На сайте говориться, что BIOS максимум тянет 4Гига для этой платы. Значит ей не судьба быть крутой. https://www.gigabyte.ru/products/page/mb/ga-945p-s3_10#sp